# Custom TextBoxFor in Razor: cannot infer usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a FormBuilder class that I can swap out depending on the UI framework, so I'm using instance methods rather than static extension methods as in other examples.  In order to create a `TextBoxFor` implementation, I'm attempting the following:

```
public class BootstrapFormBuilder<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper;
    private readonly TextWriter writer;

    public BootstrapFormBuilder(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, TextWriter writer)
    {
        this.htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public void TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, bool required = false)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        //other stuff
    }
}
```

However, on the `FromLambdaExpression` I'm getting the following error:

> The type arguments for method 'ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Expression>, ViewDataDictionary)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

As a side note, Resharper is warning me that the usage of TModel seems to be duplicating earlier usage.

How can I get the metadata line to compile? I need it in order to extract the property name and the value.

Comment: At `TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>` you're introducing a new, different `TModel` than the one applied yo your class.

Comment: So how do I restructure it to achieve what I need?

Comment: Why `TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>` returns void? Your problem seems come from `htmlHelper` which different from required usage in `TextBoxFor` method. Also, common construction of custom `HtmlHelper` for Razor view is `public static MvcHtmlString<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, ...)`.

Comment: Returning void is irrelevant to the question.  In the question text I explained why I am deviating from the pattern you mentioned.